# How to set CQ/AEM behind apache with a rewrite url

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, aem

I'm trying to set apache to rewrite anything going to http://mytest.test.cq/MySite/  to an AEM instance running on another system through a rewrite rule.

this is the virtual

```
<VirtualHost mytest.test.cq:80>
    ServerName mytest.test.cq
    documentRoot "C:/www"
    <Directory "C:/www">
        Allow from all
    </Directory>    

    RewriteEngine on    
    RewriteRule "^/MySite/(.*)" "http://my.cq.ip:4903/$1" [P]
</VirtualHost>
```

if I try to go to http://mytest.test.cq/MySite/  it does go to my AEM instance, but AEM redirect to http://mytest.test.cq/libs/granite/core/content/login.html instead.
if I write http://mytest.test.cq/MySite/libs/granite/core/content/login.html  I get the login screen, if I log in it then removed MySite again.

I thought this would be an Externalizer issue, so I configured them, but the problem persists. I've been scouring adobe's documentation without luck on a solution.

Comment: The part about MySite is unclear in your question. Does your AEM page has "MySIte" in its url path ?

Comment: No, the idea is that apache must forward any request to /MySite/ to the AEM instance, but transparently.  Think of /MySite/ as /MyAEMInstance/  the issue is that AEM seems to redirect itself to url without the "/MySite/  so it results in a 404 at the Apache level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out, so might as well post an answer.

you need to set the context-path by either setting the org.apache.felix.http.context_path property in the crx-quickstart/conf/sling.properties

or

setting a system-value -Dorg.apache.felix.http.context_path=